# Indexing Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: react-native, firebase-realtime-database, indexing, expo

What I am trying to accomplish is accessing a single item in my database.  I set up my indexing but when I query it,  I get back an empty object.
Accessing it like this shows an empty object
https://yourapp.firebaseio.com/ticket.json?orderBy=%22TicketNumber%22&equalTo=2240

```
{
  "-N6sEsiL25tQSzlNjvc4": {
    "form": {
      "Company": "Test",
      "CompanyInvolved": "Test",
      "DateCompleted": "2022-07-27T21:51:00.000Z",
      "DateDepartShop": "2022-07-19T15:43:00.000Z",
      "DateDepartSite": "2022-07-21T18:47:00.000Z",
      "Details": "D2",
      "ItemCode": "IC2",
      "MoreDetails": [
        [
          {
            "Details": "D1",
            "ItemCode": "IC1",
            "Quantity": "Q1"
          }
        ]
      ],
      "Quantity": "Q2",
      "RecievedBy": "Test",
      "Signature": "file:///Users/arod/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/4498CCA0-C6F4-4E9F-BCAE-19ADB385E758/data/Containers/Data/Application/F0A9086E-A773-43C3-861F-91D3666AB627/Library/Caches/ExponentExperienceData/%2540arod1207%252FAOS/sign.png",
      "ThirdParty": true,
      "TicketNumber": 2240,
      "TimeArriveShop": "2022-07-21T21:51:00.000Z",
      "TimeArriveSite": "2022-07-19T18:47:00.000Z",
      "TimeDepartShop": "2022-07-19T18:43:00.000Z",
      "TimeDepartSite": "2022-07-21T18:51:00.000Z",
      "TodaysDate": "2022-07-20T15:43:00.000Z"
    }
  },
```

My rules are as followed

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "true",
    ".write": "true",
      "ticket": {
            ".indexOn": "TicketNumber"
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the value you want to index lives under `form/TicketNumber` of each direct child node of the `ticket` path, that is also what you must define the index for.

So:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "true",
    ".write": "true",
      "ticket": {
            ".indexOn": "form/TicketNumber"
      }
  }
}
```

Same: that `form/TicketNumber` is also the path you need to specify for the `orderBy` parameter of your query.